# Close spoilers when clicking another

Tags: javascript, jquery

Spoiler code:

```
    <div id="a1" class="spoiler">Content</div> 
    <div id="a2" class="spoiler">Content</div>
    <div id="a3" class="spoiler">Content</div>
    <div id="a4" class="spoiler">Content</div>
    <div class="contentBoxFooter">
        <a href="a1" class = "spoilerButton">Show/Hide</a>
        <a href="a2" class = "spoilerButton">Show/Hide</a>
        <a href="a3" class = "spoilerButton">Show/Hide</a>
        <a href="a4" class = "spoilerButton">Show/Hide</a>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".spoilerButton").click(function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault()
            var foo=$(this).attr('href')
            $('#'+foo).slideToggle(1000); 
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to make another spoilers close when another spoiler it's being opened (clicked)?

Comment: I think this will work for all.

Comment: Someting like http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/28hvgm97/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close all the spoilers before opening the one you clicked. Add this to your click-event after e.preventDefault():

```
 e.preventDefault();
 $('.spoiler').hide();
```

Here's a **working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/erlingormar/4w3yLs11/1/

Answer (score 0):

Solution from @erlingormar should work. But I would suggest some improvement to the code:

```
$(".spoilerButton").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var foo=$(this).attr('href');
    $('.spoiler.active')
        .removeClass('active');
        .slideToggle(100);
    $('#'+foo)
        .addClass('active')
        .slideToggle(1000); 
});
```

In this way you would have smoother closing of the spoiler and with `.active` you have full controll over what spoiler is currently active and needs to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/22pvafer/1/)

```
var last = $(".spoiler").hide().eq(0).attr("id");
$(".spoiler").hide().eq(0).show();

$(".spoilerButton").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#' + last).slideToggle(1000);
    last = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#' + last).slideToggle(1000);
});
```

It loads the 1st spoiler and hide others.
Later displays only one Spoiler at a time.